# Sqlalchemy. Get inserted default values

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Preface:
My task is storing files on a disk, the part of a file name is a timestamp. Path to these files is storing in DB. Multiple files may have a single owner entity (one message can contain multiple attachments).
To make things easier I want to have the same timestamp for file paths in DB (it's set to `default now()`) and files on the disk.

Question:
So after insertion, I need to get back default inserted values (in most cases `primary_key_id` and `created_datetime`).

I tried:

```
db_session  # Just for clarity
<sqlalchemy.orm.session.AsyncSession object at 0x7f836691db20>

str(statement)  # Just for clarity. Don't know how to get back the original python (not an SQL) statement
'INSERT INTO users (phone_number, login, full_name, hashed_password, role) VALUES (:phone_number, :login, :full_name, :hashed_password, :role)'

query_result = await db_session.execute(statement=statement)

query_result.returned_defaults_rows  # Primary_key, but no datetime
[(243,)]

query_result.returned_defaults  # Primary_key, but no datetime
(243,)

query_result.fetchall()
[]
```

My tables:

```
Base = declarative_base()  # Main class of ORM; Put in config by suggestion https://t.me/ru_python/1450665

claims = Table(  # TODO set constraints for status
    "claims",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
```

My queries

```
async def create_item(statement: Insert, db_session: AsyncSession, detail: str = '') -> dict:
    try:  # return default created values
        statement = statement.returning(statement.table.c.id, statement.table.c.created_datetime)
        return (await db_session.execute(statement=statement)).fetchone()._asdict()
    except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError as error:
        # if psycopg2_errors.lookup(code=error.orig.pgcode) in (psycopg2_errors.UniqueViolation, psycopg2_errors.lookup):
        detail = error.orig.args[0].split('Key ')[-1].replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('"', '')
        raise HTTPException(status_code=422, detail=detail)
```

P.S. Sqlalchemy v 1.4

Comment: The ORM object should be updated when you `.flush()` the session. [This](https://pastebin.com/w1HYEdU7) works for me with plain old psycopg2. Does it not work with async?

Comment: Check [eager_defaults](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.params.eager_defaults). Add `__mapper_args__ = {"eager_defaults": True}` to your model definition, and the generated SQL will contain those columns with `RETURNING clause`. But how handle it will depend on what exactly you do - do you work with ORM, or with core sqlalchemy.

Comment: @van Thanks for commenting. I'm not sure how I'm using `sqlalchemy` (I'm just using it:) so I've updated a question to show how I used it currently.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with `session.bulk_save_objects(objects, return_defaults=True)`

Docs on this method are [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.bulk_save_objects)